# The sum of the reciprocals of Chen primes converges

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

It is well know that the The sum of the reciprocals of all primes diverges. How to prove that The sum of the reciprocals of Chen primes converges.

Comment: Is it known that the series converges? It's known that the sum of reciprocals of semi-primes diverges.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_prime

Comment: "[citation needed]"

Comment: The sum consists of two parts, the sum of the reciprocals of the twin primes and and the sum of the reciprocals of primes followed by semiprimes. The first sum converges by [Brun's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem). Thus one would need to show that the second sum converges. It might make sense to try to adapt the proof of Brun's theorem for this purpose.

Comment: I think that the result may be false! At the Math Overflow thread [An estimate for 'almost primes'?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54716/), it is claimed that the $n$th Chen prime is about $(n\log n)/(\log\log n)$. It looks like this should mean that the sum of the reciprocals of the Chen primes __diverges__. Note that Wikipedia's Talk page on Chen primes also claims it diverges, while the article itself currently says it converges. This should be resolved. Setting a bounty on this question now.

Comment: Sorry, I misquoted the Math Overflow thread, it was about semiprimes, not Chen primes.

Comment: The result is definitely true, since $\Pr(n \text{ prime} : n \le N) = \frac{1}{\log N}$ and $\Pr(n+2 \text{ semiprime} : n \le N) = \frac{\log\log N}{\log N}$, and $\sum_N \frac{\log\log N}{(\log N)^2}$ converges. Proving it though is another matter.

Comment: This posting at MO will be helpful. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58215/upper-bound-on-chen-primes-in-an-interval?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the similar method in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698449/bounding-the-number-of-semiprimes-of-the-form-2p-pm1/3534858#3534858). I found recently that this method was already also outlined in a comment by Denis in the [MO posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58215/upper-bound-on-chen-primes-in-an-interval?rq=1) I commented about:

The appearances of $C>0$ are absolute constants that are not necessarily the same.

For the twin primes, it is well known that for some absolute constant $C>0$, 
$$
|\{p: x/2<p\leq x, p+2 \textrm{ is prime } \}|\leq C \frac x{\log^2 x}.
$$
The following is Halberstam & Richart "Sieve Methods", Corollary 5.8.4 in page 179.

> Let $q$ and $h$ be integers, and let $y$ and $x$ be real numbers satisfying 
>   $$
> h\neq 0, \ \ (q,h)=1, \ \ 2|qh, \ \ 1\leq q<y\leq x.
> $$
>   Then 
>   $$
> |\{p: x-y<p\leq x, (p-h)/q = p' \}|
> $$
>   $$
> \leq 16 \prod_{p>2}\left(1-\frac1{(p-1)^2}\right)\prod_{2<p|qh}\frac{p-1}{p-2}\frac{y/q}{\log^2(y/q)}\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log\log 3|h|y}{\log(y/q)}\right)\right).
> $$

In here, $p$ and $p'$ are primes, and the implied constants in $O$-term is absolute.

Take $h=-2$, $q\leq \sqrt x$, and $y=x/2$. Then we have a simpler expression
$$
|\{p: x/2<p\leq x, (p+2)/q=p'\}|\leq C \frac{x/q}{\log^2 x}. 
$$

Then we sum up for all primes $q\leq \sqrt x$. By $\sum_{q\leq \sqrt x} \frac1q \ll \log\log x$, we obtain 
$$
|\{p: x/2<p\leq x, p \textrm{ is Chen's prime} \}|\leq C \frac{x\log\log x}{\log^2 x}. 
$$
Diadically adding this together, we have
$$
|\{ p\leq x: p \textrm{ is Chen's prime} \}|\leq C \frac{x\log\log x}{\log^2 x}. 
$$
The convergence of the reciprocal can be proved by the similar method as in Brun's constant. Let $\pi_C(t)$ be the counting function for Chen's primes up to $t$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{p \textrm{ is Chen's prime}, p\leq x} \frac1p&=\int_{2-}^x \frac1t d\pi_C(t)\\
&=\frac{\pi_C(t)}t \Bigg\vert_{2-}^x + \int_{2-}^x \frac{\pi_C(t)}{t^2}dt\\
&=\int_{2-}^{\infty}\frac{\pi_C(t)}{t^2} dt +o(1). 
\end{align}$$
The integral $\int_{2-}^{\infty}\frac{\pi_C(t)}{t^2} dt$ converges due to $$
\pi_C(t)=O\left(\frac{t\log\log t}{\log^2 t}\right),$$
and
$$
\int_2^{\infty} \frac{\log\log t}{t\log^2 t} dt
$$
converges.